# Редактирование содержимого для <textarea>

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая форма. И есть данные к ней.

```
const data = {
title: 'This is my title',
shortDescr: 'This is my shortDescr',
text: 'This is my text',
}
```

1. нужно, чтобы внутри полей ввода были соответствующие значения из объекта Data
2. должна быть возможность редактировать текст этих полей

placeholder здесь не подойдет, тк его текст нельзя будет отредактировать

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {
  title: 'This is my title',
  desc: 'This is my shortDescr',
  text: 'This is my text'
}

window.onload = function() {
  for (let name in data) {
    let field = document.querySelector(`[name=${name}]`);
    if (field) field.value = data[name];
  }
  
  let mutableFields = document.querySelectorAll('.mutable');
  mutableFields.forEach(field => {
    field.addEventListener('input', updateData);
  });
  
  function updateData(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(target.name)) {
      data[target.name] = target.value;
    }
    
    console.info(data);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="title" type="text" class="mutable">
<input name="desc" type="text" class="mutable">
<textarea name="text" class="mutable"></textarea>
```

Comment: без использования querySelectorAll() есть вариант? @Bamberg

Comment: @Chilik Для каждого поля можно сделать так:
```document.querySelector('[name="title"]').addEventListener('input', updateData)```

Comment: с useForm возможно? @Bamberg